# Message from webpage, leave or stay

Tags: html

I have a php page with an HTML form that works fine in chrome and firefox, but in IE this popup shows up upon submitting the form:

[image]

It's confusing because I don't have any sort of validation on the page, so what is it that returns false?

```
<form name="qualityform" action="" method="post">
     <input type="hidden" name="process" value="yes" />
     <input type="hidden" name="ref" value="<?=$refvalue?>" />
     <input type="hidden" name="email" value="<?=$emailvalue?>" />
     <input type="hidden" name="interface" value="<?=$interface?>" />
     <input type="hidden" name="cemail" value="<?=$cemail?>" />
          <input type="hidden" name="greeting" value="<?=$greeting?>" />

    <table border="0" width="100%">
      <tbody>
        <tr class="dq_allTravelers " id="tr_qid12" height="30">
          <td width="30%"><font style="font-size: 12px;" face="Verdana"><?=$language[$interface]['over_all_Satisfaction']?>:</font></td>
          <td width="10%" class="detailsRatings" onMouseOver="ta.call(&#39;ta.userreview.addDynamicRatingObject&#39;, event, this)"><label class="visuallyHidden"> <?=$language[$interface]['over_all_Satisfaction']?>
              <select name="over_all_Satisfaction" id="over_all_Satisfaction">
                <option value="">Select one</option>
                <option value="1"> 1 </option>
                <option value="2"> 2 </option>
                <option value="3"> 3 </option>
                <option value="4"> 4 </option>
                <option value="5"> 5 </option>
              </select>
            </label>
            <span id="qid12_bubbles" class="rate rate_s gs00 qid12"> <img src="<?php echo $pageURL;?>images/ratings-v7.png"> </span></td>
          <td width="20%" id="AMENITY_RATING_BUBBLE_TEXT_qid12" style="color:#000; font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px; font-weight:bold;"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="dq_allTravelers " id="tr_qid12" height="30">
          <td><font style="font-size: 12px;" face="Verdana"><?=$language[$interface]['Will_you_hire']?>?</font></td>
          <td><input type="radio" name="will_you_hire_us" value="Yes" />&nbsp;<font style="font-size: 12px;" face="Verdana">Yes</font>&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="radio" name="will_you_hire_us" value="No" />&nbsp;<font style="font-size: 12px;" face="Verdana">No</font></td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="dq_allTravelers " id="tr_qid12" height="30">
          <td><font style="font-size: 12px;" face="Verdana"><?=$language[$interface]['Will_you_recommend']?>?</font></td>
          <td><input type="radio" name="will_you_recommend" value="Yes" />&nbsp;<font style="font-size: 12px;" face="Verdana">Yes</font>&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="radio" name="will_you_recommend" value="No" />&nbsp;<font style="font-size: 12px;" face="Verdana">No</font></td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>

        <tr><td class="3">&nbsp;

        </td></tr>
        <tr class="dq_allTravelers " id="tr_qid13" height="30">
          <td><font style="font-size: 12px;" face="Verdana"><?=$language[$interface]['Communication']?>:</font></td>
          <td class="detailsRatings" onMouseOver="ta.call(&#39;ta.userreview.addDynamicRatingObject&#39;, event, this)"><label class="visuallyHidden"> <?=$language[$interface]['Communication']?>
              <select name="Communication" id="Communication">
                <option value="">Select one</option>
                <option value="1"> 1 </option>
                <option value="2"> 2 </option>
                <option value="3"> 3 </option>
                <option value="4"> 4 </option>
                <option value="5"> 5 </option>
              </select>
            </label>
            <span id="qid13_bubbles" class="rate rate_s gs00 qid13"> <img src="<?php echo $pageURL;?>images/ratings-v7.png"> </span></td>
          <td id="AMENITY_RATING_BUBBLE_TEXT_qid13" style="color:#000; font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px; font-weight:bold;"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="dq_allTravelers " id="tr_qid14" height="30">
          <td><font style="font-size: 12px;" face="Verdana"><?=$language[$interface]['Quality']?>:</font></td>
          <td class="detailsRatings" onMouseOver="ta.call(&#39;ta.userreview.addDynamicRatingObject&#39;, event, this)"><label class="visuallyHidden"> <?=$language[$interface]['Quality_of_our_work']?>
              <select name="Quality" id="Quality">
                <option value="">Select one</option>
                <option value="1"> 1 </option>
                <option value="2"> 2 </option>
                <option value="3"> 3 </option>
                <option value="4"> 4 </option>
                <option value="5"> 5 </option>
              </select>
            </label>
            <span id="qid14_bubbles" class="rate rate_s gs00 qid14"> <img src="<?php echo $pageURL;?>images/ratings-v7.png"> </span></td>
          <td id="AMENITY_RATING_BUBBLE_TEXT_qid14" style="color:#000; font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px; font-weight:bold;"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="dq_allTravelers " id="tr_qid15" height="30">
          <td><font style="font-size: 12px;" face="Verdana"><?=$language[$interface]['Speed_of_our_work']?>:</font></td>
          <td class="detailsRatings" onMouseOver="ta.call(&#39;ta.userreview.addDynamicRatingObject&#39;, event, this)"><label class="visuallyHidden"> <?=$language[$interface]['Speed']?>
              <select name="Speed" id="Speed">
                <option value="">Select one</option>
                <option value="1"> 1 </option>
                <option value="2"> 2 </option>
                <option value="3"> 3 </option>
                <option value="4"> 4 </option>
                <option value="5"> 5 </option>
              </select>
            </label>
            <span id="qid15_bubbles" class="rate rate_s gs00 qid15"> <img src="<?php echo $pageURL;?>images/ratings-v7.png"> </span></td>
          <td id="AMENITY_RATING_BUBBLE_TEXT_qid15" style="color:#000; font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px; font-weight:bold;"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="dq_allTravelers " id="tr_qid16" height="30">
          <td><font style="font-size: 12px;" face="Verdana"><?=$language[$interface]['Value']?>:</font></td>
          <td class="detailsRatings" onMouseOver="ta.call(&#39;ta.userreview.addDynamicRatingObject&#39;, event, this)"><label class="visuallyHidden"> <?=$language[$interface]['Value']?>
              <select name="Value" id="Value">
                <option value="">Select one</option>
                <option value="1"> 1 </option>
                <option value="2"> 2 </option>
                <option value="3"> 3 </option>
                <option value="4"> 4 </option>
                <option value="5"> 5 </option>
              </select>
            </label>
            <span id="qid16_bubbles" class="rate rate_s gs00 qid16"> <img src="<?php echo $pageURL;?>images/ratings-v7.png"> </span></td>
          <td id="AMENITY_RATING_BUBBLE_TEXT_qid16" style="color:#000; font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px; font-weight:bold;"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr height="25">
          <td valign="top"><font style="font-size:12px;" face="Verdana"><?=$language[$interface]['comment']?>:</font></td>
          <td colspan="2"><textarea name="comment" class="element text medium" style="width:200px; height:100px;font-family: Lato;font-size: 13px;"></textarea></td>
        </tr>
        <tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
        <tr><td colspan="3">
        <input type="submit" name="submit_form" value="<?=$language[$interface]['Submit']?>" class="button_text" style="font: bold 16px Lato;color: #fff;background-color: #09bef2;width: 286px;border:0;height:26px"/>
        </td></tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    </form>
```

Thanks

Comment: Have you partially filled out a form, without submitting?

Comment: I think you need to return an empty string "", instead of `false` from your `onbeforeunload` event handler.

Comment: We need to see some code to be able to figure out what is going wrong.

Comment: @j08691 both on ie9 and ie10

Comment: @SableFoste even if I filled it all it does the same thing when I hit submit!

Comment: What Scunliffe says. This looks like an `onbeforeunload` message. No way to say any more without seeing code

Comment: @scunliffe I didnt refer to onbeforeunload in the script, could it still be the reason ?

Comment: Are you sure you aren't including any external JavaScripts?

Comment: If you are using a framework (e.g. Cake, Zend, CodeIgnitor...) it may be applying the JavaScript. Try "grepping" (searching) your code base for `onbeforeunload` or `onunload` there's likely a reference somewhere in there.  Note that in Internet Explorer - even an "in-page" link that calls JavaScript will trigger the "hey a page navigation is occurring" event and thus even if you don't leave the page it may show this dialog. MSDN Documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/ie/ms536907%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: @scunliffe Thanks a lot for your help, I dont use a framework but there's a reference to jQuery files, i'll check if any call to onunload or onbeforeunload is made.